# Make the android questions widget handle my imprecise fingers

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-widgets

Love the new questions widget, but it looks like I have to be very precise when tapping to refresh the question. I have to hit the icon dead on; tapping above, below or to the right behaves as if i'd tapped the question.

Please give me a bit of leeway when tapping to refresh.

Comment: This has been seriously bugging me recently, so expect it fixed in the next update.

Comment: Fixed in the next update, I'll submit an answer when that update is going out.

Comment: @Kasra When can we expect the next release? I've been waiting.

Comment: @ADTC Hopefully within the next week or two. We've been making some big changes.

Comment: @Kasra On a related note, pressing the hardware back key after opening a question from the widget takes me to the feed. I expect it to go back to the home screen with the widget because that's where I came from. The unfriendly back behavior is generally present in the app throughout but this instance is particularly annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed on the newest update, 1.0.49, currently on the alpha channel. If all goes well it'll be fixed for all within 47 hours.

Comment: Thanks! 47 hours, that's pretty precise. Can anyone be on the alpha channel or is it devs/SE only?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Anyone can be on it! It's the same as we used for the initial release, if you want to join send a request to join this G+ community: https://plus.google.com/communities/116770445014869505908